# Pytorch Argrelmax function (or C++)

Tags: python, c++, scipy, pytorch

I'm trying to find the equivalent pytorch (or C++) for scipy.signal.argrelmax(), which finds the peaks in a 1D array with some padding. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.argrelmax.html

Here's what I've come up with and it is faster than scipy.signal.argrelmax - but I'm missing a fast solution to the last step which deletes peaks within some window.

```
import torch

# initalize an array (not the one in plot below)
gpu_max = torch.rand(100000)

# find peaks and troughs by subtracting shifted versions
gpu_temp1 = gpu_max[1:-1]-gpu_max[:-2]
gpu_temp2 = gpu_max[1:-1]-gpu_max[2:]

# and checking where both shifts are positive;
out1 = torch.where(gpu_temp1>0, gpu_temp1*0+1, gpu_temp1*0)
out2 = torch.where(gpu_temp2>0, out1, gpu_temp2*0)

# argrelmax containing all peaks
argrelmax_gpu = torch.nonzero(out2, out=None)+1
```

So the top plot which marks every single relmaxpeak is pretty fast. But need the bottom one - which comes from scipy.signal.argrelmax() and uses a 30sample time window (i.e. it only returns maxima within a 60 time point window).

EDIT: I've updated code to reflect updated torch.nonzero() search.  But still need to figure out how to do the last step (in figure below).
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so someone on pytorch forums did have a pretty good solution: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/pytorch-argrelmax-or-c-function/36404

Here's the full answer in case it gets deleted:

```
    a = #1D Array of  your choice
    window_maxima = torch.nn.functional.max_pool1d_with_indices(a.view(1,1,-1), width, 1, padding=width//2)[1].squeeze()
    candidates = window_maxima.unique()
    nice_peaks = candidates[(window_maxima[candidates]==candidates).nonzero()]
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing in PyTorch and I cannot think of an easy way to implement it efficiently in terms of the ready-made functions, sorry. Coding this in C++ to just work is fairly simple, making it run in parallel with large grain (think CPU) is also fairly simple, making this run on GPU with 1000s of cores is more tricky because you have to find the right balance between parallelism and data reuse between the computation for subsequent indices. If you decide to go this way nevertheless, the [tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/advanced/cpp_extension.html) on custom native extensions is quite good.

As for the `torch.where` issue, this functionality is provided via [`torch.nonzero`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/torch.html#torch.nonzero).

EDIT: Please note that your approach above can be extended to any size of padding by iterating in a `for` loop and it won't be less performant algorithmically than the `scipy` thing, which also does a pretty naive windowed application of `argmax`, instead of iterating with some clever priority list. Therefore, with GPU support, you may still see acceptable performance (depending on your use case).

Comment: Jatentaki: thanks for the input; the torch.nonzero function is definitely very useful.   I'm hoping someone has implemented the full argrelmax somewhere. My version is a pretty good start, though I feel there's faster ways to do this.